# AS3 Worker not functioning properly in Flash CC debug or release, except when published

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, flashdevelop, flash-cc

Today I tried to do some background work with the AS3 Worker class.

However, I am experiencing weird behavior when developping my AIR desktop application in Flash CC on Windows 7. Consider this simple file for the main "thread":

```
////////////////
// MainThread.as
////////////////
package{
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.system.*;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.utils.*;
    public class MainThread extends MovieClip
    {
        [Embed(source="WorkerThread.swf", mimeType="application/octet-stream")]
        private static var WORKER_SWF:Class;

        var mainToWorker:MessageChannel;
        var workerToMain:MessageChannel;
        var workerToMainStartup:MessageChannel;

        public function MainThread()
        {
            var workerBytes:ByteArray = new WORKER_SWF() as ByteArray;
            var worker:Worker = WorkerDomain.current.createWorker(workerBytes, true);

            // Send to worker
            mainToWorker = Worker.current.createMessageChannel(worker);
            worker.setSharedProperty("mainToWorker", mainToWorker);

            // Receive from worker
            workerToMain = worker.createMessageChannel(Worker.current);
            workerToMain.addEventListener(Event.CHANNEL_MESSAGE, onWorkerToMain);
            worker.setSharedProperty("workerToMain", workerToMain);

            // Receive startup message from worker
            workerToMainStartup = worker.createMessageChannel(Worker.current);
            workerToMainStartup.addEventListener(Event.CHANNEL_MESSAGE, onWorkerToMainStartup);
            worker.setSharedProperty("workerToMainStartup", workerToMainStartup);

            worker.start();

            trace("hi");
        }

        private function onWorkerToMain(ev:Event): void
        {
        }

        private function onWorkerToMainStartup(ev:Event): void
        {
            var success:Boolean = workerToMainStartup.receive() as Boolean;
            trace(success);
            if (!success)
            {
                // ... handle worker startup failure case
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then this file for the worker (the swf of this file is built in FlashDevelop):

```
//////////////////
// WorkerThread.as
//////////////////
package{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.system.*;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.filesystem.*;

    public class WorkerThread extends MovieClip
    {
        public var mainToWorker:MessageChannel;
        public var workerToMain:MessageChannel;
        public var workerToMainStartup:MessageChannel;

        public function WorkerThread()
        {
            // Receive from main
            mainToWorker = Worker.current.getSharedProperty("mainToWorker");
            mainToWorker.addEventListener(Event.CHANNEL_MESSAGE, onMainToWorker);

            // Send to main
            workerToMain = Worker.current.getSharedProperty("workerToMain");

            // Send startup message to main
            workerToMainStartup = Worker.current.getSharedProperty("workerToMainStartup");
            workerToMainStartup.send(true);

            trace("Hello from worker world.");
            var file:File = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath("MyTextFile.txt");
            var stream:FileStream = new FileStream();
            stream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);
            stream.writeUTFBytes("ZA WARUDO.");
            stream.close();
        }

        private function onMainToWorker(event:Event): void
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Here are the problems I'm experiencing **when building and launching the application from Flash CC**:

- Traces from worker world can't be seen in the Flash CC debugger.
- The onWorkerToMainStartup listener is never fired, despite the worker running (tracing `worker.state` after a brief delay will confirm that).
- The worker is supposed to write a file but that never happens.

However...

- The worker **will write the file once I stop the debugger in Flash CC.**
- **After publishing the app and executing it from Windows Explorer, it works as it should** (meaning, the file is written in the background, while the application runs, as expected).

This is crazy. Why does this happen?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problems a while back.

I never managed to get the trace output piped to the debugger. However I was able to find the worker trace output in the log txt file here:
`%APPDATA%\Macromedia\Flash Player\Logs\`

As for worker SWF's not advancing during debugging - try compiling your worker SWFS as Release, not Debug.